# Event fired after clicking the 'delete' of right click context menu of textbox

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I want to perform some activity when user deletes the data from textbox using the 'delete' of right click context menu.

- Event.ONMOUSEDOWN event doesn't works.
- Javascript doesen't provide event for ondelete

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to catch the "delete" on the context menu.

**Workaround 1**

You can use ONCHANGE and do what you need to do when the textbox value is "".

Or you could use ONKEYPRESS and either detect the "delete" stroke, either check the textbox content on each key stroke.

Use UI handlers for this.

```
@UiHandler("myTextBox")
protected void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent e) {
    // do something...
}
```

**Workaround 2**

If you want to catch the right click event do as such.

```
myTextBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {          
   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      if (event.getNativeEvent().getButton() == NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT) {
         // code...
      }            
   }
});
```

Or, again, use UIHandlers.

**Workaround 3**

If you are still unhappy and still want to catch the "delete" click from the context menu you only have one option left. You should write your own context menu. Use event.preventDefault() on right mouse button click and show you own "context menu widget" instead.
You can write a contextMenuHandler as explained here: https://confluence.clazzes.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=425996

Comment: when we mouse right click on textbox, contex menu appears.. And i want event on the 'delete' item shown.

Comment: Yes. Creating my own context menu widget is the only option left. Because when user right clicks, I can't assume that he will only select delete. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Alright, have a look here for the context menu implementation https://confluence.clazzes.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=425996. Don't forget to validate the answer :)